# Droid X: DLNA Client & Server for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, android, phone

I just got my Droid X and I'm trying to figure out how do I copy Video & Pictures that I've made with my phone over to my Mac.

It has this DLNA and I can't find decent client for my Mac so I can access it, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [Medialink](http://www.nullriver.com/products/medialink) ?